# flink on minikub - Could not resolve ResourceManager address

Tags: apache-flink, minikube

I followed the instructions from https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/ to setup a session mode flink cluster as in the section "Starting a Kubernetes Cluster (Session Mode)" with the following commands:

```
# Configuration and service definition
$ kubectl create -f flink-configuration-configmap.yaml
$ kubectl create -f jobmanager-service.yaml
# Create the deployments for the cluster
$ kubectl create -f jobmanager-session-deployment.yaml
$ kubectl create -f taskmanager-session-deployment.yaml
```

The taskmanager pod keeps crashing. The taskmanager log shows:

```
2022-02-28 03:41:40,543 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [java.net.UnknownHostException: flink-jobmanager: Temporary failure in name resolution]
2022-02-28 03:41:40,555 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2022-02-28 03:42:00,584 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2022-02-28 03:42:10,594 INFO  akka.remote.transport.ProtocolStateActor                     [] - No response from remote for outbound association. Associate timed out after [20000 ms].
2022-02-28 03:42:10,596 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                       [] - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123]] Caused by: [No response from remote for outbound association. Associate timed out after [20000 ms].]
2022-02-28 03:42:10,605 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2022-02-28 03:42:30,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*, retrying in 10000 ms: Could not connect to rpc endpoint under address akka.tcp://flink@flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*.
2022-02-28 03:42:40,052 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Fatal error occurred in TaskExecutor akka.tcp://flink@10.244.205.198:6122/user/rpc/taskmanager_0.
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.exceptions.RegistrationTimeoutException: Could not register at the ResourceManager within the specified maximum registration duration 300000 ms. This indicates a problem with this instance. Terminating now.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.registrationTimeout(TaskExecutor.java:1449) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor.lambda$startRegistrationTimeout$17(TaskExecutor.java:1434) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.14.3.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRunAsync$4(AkkaRpcActor.java:455) ~[flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:455) ~[flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:213) ~[flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163) ~[flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) [flink-rpc-akka_dcfe8153-9945-448e-897a-6dec4f3d2704.jar:1.14.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) [?:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) [?:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) [?:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) [?:1.8.0_322]
2022-02-28 03:42:40,066 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner      [] - Fatal error occurred while executing the TaskManager. Shutting it down...
```

Does the error mean that taskmanager can not resolve the flink-jobmanager to the flink-jobmanager service cluster ip?

The flink-jobmanager service is up:

```
(base) ~/cloudmap3/cloudmap3-k8s/flink $ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
flink-jobmanager   ClusterIP   10.111.160.112   <none>        6123/TCP,6124/TCP,8081/TCP   83m
kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      32d
```

How should I debug this issue?

To add some more info:
The coreDNS pod shows nodenotready. The log from the pod shows:

```
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[WARNING] plugin/kubernetes: starting server with unsynced Kubernetes API
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 08e2b174e0f0a30a2e82df9c995f4a34
CoreDNS-1.8.4
linux/amd64, go1.16.4, 053c4d5
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" failed: Get "http://:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" took more than 1s: 2.607635169s
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" failed: Get "http://:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" failed: Get "http://:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" failed: Get "http://:8080/health": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[WARNING] plugin/health: Local health request to "http://:8080/health" took more than 1s: 1.885799651s
```

Comment: What about `flink-jobmanager` pod, is it running without problems?

Comment: flink-jobmanager pod is runing fine without crashloop.

Comment: Can you add information about the yaml files you are using? For example: Name of the section in Appendix and file name.

Comment: The files used are in the section "Session cluster resource definitions", and they are: 
flink-configuration-configmap.yaml,
jobmanager-service.yaml,
jobmanager-session-deployment.yaml,
taskmanager-session-deployment.yaml.

However, it seems to be a coreDNS issue since the logs from coreDNS says 
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: What I see from my side is: `flink-configuration-configmap.yaml`  and `jobmanager-service.yaml` in [Common cluster resource definition](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#common-cluster-resource-definitions) section. There is no file with name `jobmanager-session-deployment.yaml` in [Session cluster resource definitions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#session-cluster-resource-definitions) section. Which of both you are using?

Comment: It is jobmanager-session-deployment-non-ha.yaml in [Session cluster resource definitions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#session-cluster-resource-definitions)

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the coredns pod, the error from coredns pod `[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"` goes away and the flink taskmanager can register with the jobmanager.